# Is there any way to forcefully watch node-sass with CLI?

Tags: css, node.js, sass, node-modules, node-sass

Is there any way to compile `node-sass` forcefully *even if there is **no change** in the `SCSS` files*. Like the `compass watch --force` in `ruby-sass`

Now I am using the following command with the npm script

```
node-sass --watch assets/scss -o assets/css --output-style compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

```
node-sass --output-style=compressed --output=assets/css assets/sass
```

Thay will compile all `.scss` files located in `assets/sass` into `assets/css`.

You code uses the `--watch` argument; that means that `node-sass` will be watching `assets/scss` for any `.scss` or `.sass` file that changes, to compile the files.

You can learn more about node-sass [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). Hope it helps!